# Git branch remove pushed changes locally

Tags: git, github, branch

I program in branches and push the branches so that I can make pull requests. After doing such, I need to go back to origin master (or at least a copy of the code in the current origin master), and create a new branch from there without the changes I had just made in the other branch.

I can change branches and create them just fine, but I can never get a version of the code without the changes I had just made. What is the proper procedure for doing this?

Comment: `git checkout -b branch_name origin/master` ?

Comment: @AndrewC Thanks, I knew it should be simple, but for some reason I was still missing it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that u have created a repository with your master branch you can do the following.

git checkout master (you are in master branch now)

git checkout -b your-feature-branch
(No u are on your new branch branched off of master)

apply your changes on this branch. Whenever u want to start a fresh feature just commit everything on the above feature branch and go back to your master
git checkout master (now your code is clean without the previous changes)

I think that should do it..

Answer (score 0):

My issue is that the files weren't being handled as I was git adding them all manually every time and they weren't being tracked, so I needed to git checkout each file.